# HTTP Post Windows Phone

Tags: image, windows-phone, http-post

I'm making a call to an API that consists in a HTTP Post request. The data i want to post is an image, properly converted into a byte array. 
The response is not as expected, and i want to know what is the error: is it my code or is it the API? This is the code that i'm using

```
Image i = new Image();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/dmoc.jpeg", UriKind.Relative));
            testImage.Source = bi;

            byte[] rawimage = ImageConverter.ImageToBytes(bi);

        try
        {

            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://private-anon-6cf48a749-yugiohprices.apiary-mock.com/");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {
                //HttpRequestHeader.ContentType

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));
                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/match_card_image", new ByteArrayContent(rawimage)))
                {
                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    postTxt.Text = responseData;
                }
            }
}
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

where ImageConverter is my class.

Comment: I recommend trying the API with the inputs you are giving it separately from the app if you don't trust it. One really handy tool for Doing HTTP requests is Postman. Here's a link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop    Figuring out if the API is working right is a good first step.

Comment: I tried it, the response is the same (not as expected). I filled the body of my request with an image from my PC, is this the right way?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you API is not working. It's impossible for anyone to say, since we don't know what your API is, what input and output are expected, or even what format the input and output are expected to be. We're going to need a LOT more contextual info to be able to help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for your help, i found the problem: it is in the API itself. I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: The url i was trying before was a sort of test, but even with the right one it does not work